# ASP.NET MVC View-Model: reload from backend on invalid post or put all properties in hidden inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3, and I've got a view-model with several properties, some of which are for display to the user, and some of which are used as inputs from the user and may have default values.  I'm using the same view-model for GET requests (the only parameter is an identifier for what to get) and for posts, which take the entire view-model as a parameter in the action.  My controller populates the view-modelwith entities retrieved through a business logic layer that pulls entities from an NHibernate session.

Is it better to put hidden inputs in the view for all of the read-only fields so they will be present if the page is rendered after a post with an invalid view-model, or is it better to only use inputs that the user really supplies the data and reload the rest of the backend and merge it in?

Thanks!

edit:

**And why?**

edit:

The controller generally looks something like this:

```
public class MyController : BaseController /* BaseController provide BizLogic object */
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditSomething(Int32 id)
    {
        MyDomainObject = base.BizLogic.GetMyDomainObjectById(id);
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        model.Id = id;
        model.ReadOnly1 = MyDomainObject.Field1;
        model.Readonly2 = MyDomainObject.Field2;
        model.UserInput3 = MyDomainObject.Field3;
        model.UserInput4 = MyDomainObject.Field4;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditSomethingMyViewModel model)
    {
        PerformComplexValidationNotDoneByAttributes(model);
        if (ModelState.Valid)
        {
            BizLogicSaveTransferObject transferObject =
                new BizLogicSaveTransferObject();
            transferObject.Id = model.Id;
            transferObject.Field3 = model.UserInput3;
            transferObject.Field4 = model.UserInput4;
            base.BizLogic.SaveDomainObject(transferObject);

            return RedirectToAction("EditSomething", new { id = model.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            #if reload_non_input_fields_from_db

            MyDomainObject = base.BizLogic.GetMyDomainObjectById(model.Id);
            model.ReadOnly1 = MyDomainObject.Field1;
            model.Readonly2 = MyDomainObject.Field2;

            #endif

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

The view looks something like this:

```
# Html.BeginForm();
${Html.ValidationSummary()}
    <p>ID: ${Model.Id}</p><input type="hidden" name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.Id)}" value="${Model.Id" />
    <p>Read Only One: ${Model.ReadOnly1}</p><!-- uncomment if not reload_non_input_fields_from_db <input type="hidden" name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.ReadOnly1)}" value="${Model.ReadOnly1}" />-->
    <p>Read Only Two: ${Model.ReadOnly2}</p><!-- uncomment if not reload_non_input_fields_from_db <input type="hidden" name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.ReadOnly2)}" value="${Model.ReadOnly2}" />-->
    <p>Input Three: ${Model.UserInput3}</p><input type="hidden" name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.UserInput3)}" value="${Model.UserInput3}" />
    <p>Input Three: ${Model.UserInput4}</p><input type="hidden" name="${Html.NameFor(m => m.UserInput3)}" value="${Model.UserInput4}" />
# Html.EndForm();
```

Comment: Can you provide some code please so that we can see exactly what it is you are trying to achieve?  Controller (get and post actions), view and view model examples please.

Comment: I've added some examples.  The view model is pretty trivial.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

There's no sense in putting any inputs into the page if they are read-only (except for the unique record ID field, of course).  As you wrote, merge the fields that the user is allowed to modify.

You'll need to merge the fields either way; for read-only fields, those should never be over-written based on data you sent to the client, and assume will come back to you the same.  Even if you make the inputs "hidden", they're not really hidden; they can easily be modified by anyone who knows how to use Firebug, for example.

Comment: So the complexity of merging the data in the controller action is less burdensome than putting all of the fields in the view?  I'm inclined to agree with that, except *maybe* some read-only fields that confirm user selections via AJAX. 

I posted some example code above.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Spark view engine but it looks like your form only displays information and has hidden fields?

However, I believe that what your actually trying to achieve is to allow the user to edit UserInput3 and UserInput4.  Therefore, I've rewrote your controller and view to what I think your trying to achieve and have included comments containing my answers.  The view is written using the razor view engine so you will have to tranfer to Spark.

I hope this is what you wanted:

**Controller:**

```
//HttpGet has been removed as this is implied
public ViewResult EditSomething(Int32 id)
{
    MyDomainObject = base.BizLogic.GetMyDomainObjectById(id);
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel()  
    {
        //this uses C# 3.0 object initializer syntax
        model.Id = MyDomainObject.Id,
        model.ReadOnly1 = MyDomainObject.Field1,
        model.Readonly2 = MyDomainObject.Field2,
        model.UserInput3 = MyDomainObject.Field3,
        model.UserInput4 = MyDomainObject.Field4
    };
    return View(model);
}

//It is common (although not required) for the Post action to have the same name as the Get action
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditSomething (MyViewModel model)
{
    //I recommend you take a look at FluentValidation to validate your models.
    //Hopefully, you should no longer have the limitations of the data attributes and you will not require PerformComplexValidationNotDoneByAttributes()
    //This will allow you to just simply check the model state.
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        BizLogicSaveTransferObject transferObject = new BizLogicSaveTransferObject()
        {
            //You should write the new user inputs to the database.
            transferObject.Id = model.Id,
            transferObject.Field3 = model.UserInput3,
            transferObject.Field4 = model.UserInput4
        };
        base.BizLogic.SaveDomainObject(transferObject);

        //You were previously returning a redirect to the same action???  Do you need to pass the id?
        return RedirectToAction("NextAction", new { id = model.Id });
    }

    //Note: The else is not required as a return was used in the previous if.

    //IN ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION, you should re-retrieve the domain object from the database to get the information to display again
    //as these values will be null/default values in your model.
    //There will be a performance cost in retrieving this information again but you could not rely on this data to be sent from the user.
    //Nor, should it have been included in the request as you should keep the size of the request down as indicated here:
    //http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html
    MyDomainObject = base.BizLogic.GetMyDomainObjectById(model.Id);
    model.ReadOnly1 = MyDomainObject.Field1;
    model.Readonly2 = MyDomainObject.Field2;

    return View(model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MyViewModel

<!--
    The read only fields which are only used to display information have been included outside of the form.
    As this information is only used for display purposes we do not want to send it back as:
    1. It will increase the size of the request.
    2. We can not rely on it as a mischievous user may have tampered with it.
-->
<p>Read Only One: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReadOnly1)</p>
<p>Read Only Two: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReadOnly2)</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!--
        The id is still passed using a hidden field as you still need to identify the database entity in the post action.
        I have not displayed the id as there seemed little point.
        Again, a user could change this id so you would need to check that the id exists in the database.
    -->
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

    <!--
        The user inputs do not need to have their previous values passed via hidden fields.
        This increases the size of the request and by the looks of it you are not using them in the post controller.
    -->
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInput3)</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInput4)</p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```